# Prolog, about how to form better clauses

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif, prolog-cut, logical-purity

I have following clauses:

```
num_parent(adam, X) :- !, X = 0.  
num_parent(eve, X) :- !, X = 0.  
num_parent(X, 2).
```

When I typed the query:

```
num_parent(eve,X).
```

It only returns:

```
X = 0.
```

which is what I want.

But when I typed this query:

```
num_parent(X,0).
```

it only returns:

```
X = adam.
```

So how can I modify the clauses to make it return:

```
X = adam;
X = eve.
```

Thanks

Comment: Just remove the `!`?

Comment: Actually cut can result in a lot of results you did not take into account. Since it is sometimes hard for people to reason multidirectional.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't explain the problem clearly, the original clauses didn't have any !, when I type num_parent(eve,X), because of the last clause, except for returning X = 0, it also returned X = 2, which is not what I want. To avoid getting X = 2, I add ! in first two clauses, when I type num_parent(X,0), it only returns X = adam now, but I want to get X = eve too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try to formulate what you want in plain English. You probably want to say:

> Everyone has two parents except Adam and Eve who have none.

What about Lilith? Never mind, let's stick to your reading.

```
num_parent(Person, 2) :-
   dif(Person, adam),
   dif(Person, eve).
num_parent(adam, 0).
num_parent(eve, 0).
```

As you can see, it is a bit cumbersome to define this: You have to mention each exceptional person twice. Easy to make an error.

With [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868)  available in `library(reif)`
for
[SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl) and
[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl)
you can write more succinctly:

```
num_parent(Person, Num) :-
   if_( ( Person = adam ; Person = eve ), Num = 0, Num = 2 ).
```

And now some uses:

```
?- num_parent(eve, Num).
   Num = 0.
?- num_parent(X, 0).
   X = adam
;  X = eve
;  false.
?- num_parent(X, 2).
   dif(X, eve), dif(X, adam).
?- num_parent(lilith, 2).
   true.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for rephrasing and solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The programs returns only `X = adam` because you inserted the cut `!`. The cut is used when you have found the right rules and you don't need to do further evaluations, but it cuts all the other solutions.

In your case

```
num_parent(adam, X) :- !, X = 0.  
num_parent(eve, X) :- !, X = 0.  
num_parent(_, 2). %replaced num_parent(X, 2) with num_parent(_, 2) to avoid singleton variable
```

`num_parent(X, 0)` returns only `X = adam`.

If you write

```
num_parent(adam, X) :- X = 0.  
num_parent(eve, X) :- !, X = 0.  
num_parent(_, 2).
```

the solution will be `X = adam` and `X = eve`, and in this case:

```
num_parent(adam, X) :- X = 0.  
num_parent(eve, X) :- X = 0.  
num_parent(_, 2).
```

the solution will be `X = adam`, `X = eve` and `false` because the query `num_parent(X, 0)` doesn't unify with `num_parent(_, 2)`.

You can better see this behavior using the tracer.